Ubuntu 24 lts not booting after Nvidia driver installation
I installed a nvidia driver on my Ubuntu 24 lts running on a dell workstation running a nvidia quadro rtx 3500.
After the installation, ubuntu showed the boot screen with ubuntu on it, but the turning ubuntu sign did not appear. It froze right there.
I tried different driver versions (540, 550, 555, 560), non of them worked. I istalled with apt.
The only solution to get the computer to boot again was to enter advanced options/ bash/ and purge nvidia.
Any ideas what i could try or what logs to look at?
Thanks in advance.
